# Combining Delphi & remobjects via SSL

Tags: delphi, remobjects

I'm in the development of a server client solution.
The server is written in delphi and the client written in c#, and we're using RemObjects 5 (xml webservice thingy) to perform the communication.

Now, I've got a working soluting using HTTP, but of course we would like to use HTTPS using.

I've looked at OpenSSL earlier, but it seems to be a pain to actually get a reasonable recent version to work together with Delphi.

I would like suggestions for 3rd party software, libraries, or even hints, tutorials and references. It's more or less anything goes short of abandoning remobjects and delphi.

Necessary requirements:
Delphi 2006, 2007 or 2010. 
Visual studio 2005 / 2008 or 2010.

Much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need SSL? What does it offer that the RemObjects SDK's own encryption options don't offer? I use the supplied encryption and it works well.

Comment: @mj2008: because from a security point of view it is better to leave encryption to the encryption experts and communication to the communication experts.

Comment: Oh, I kick myself for missing the internal encryption. Must have put my blind side to it. Thank you mj2008 for pointing out something obvious.
Secondly there's a chance that we'll change or add from remobjects bin-messages, to SOAP which we've used to enable PHP to interface it as well, and then I need something that does not make firefox complain about ~ "invalid authentication/encryption level" or somewhat. That's where OpenSSL 0.96 to 0.98f-g makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using RemObjects SDK, you can use OpenSSL by using one of the server channels that are implemented using Indy, like TROIndyHTTPServer; this channel uses Indy internally, and provides access to the internal Indy component via its IndyServer property.

You can assign a TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL to TROIndyHTTPServer.IndyServer.IOHander property to use SSL in your communication.

You need OpenSSL compiled for Indy, which you can download the latest version from this link:

http://blog.digivendo.com/2009/11/openssl-v0-9-8l-for-indy/

Answer (score 1):

Also tried Indy SSL demo?

http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Demos/index.EN.aspx
http://adg.bmpcoe.org/IndySSL/

[Edit]
Done some googling:
http://secureblackbox.com/article_remobjects.html
http://devcenter.remobjects.com/articles/?id={EF02D5FA-4536-4D5F-BF3D-50676397D7E0}

Comment: Thank you for your input.
I've heard about blackbox before, but I've never seen it in action. Anyone who can recommend it?

By the way, the second link is incorrect, it shoud be:
http://adg.bmpcoe.org/download/indyssl/index.html